# Why is MATLAB unable to determine the number of frames in a video file?

Tags: matlab, video

I am trying to reproduce [these results](http://people.csail.mit.edu/mrub/vidmag/) obtained by researchers from MIT. The code is available [here](http://people.csail.mit.edu/mrub/evm/#code).

These are the warnings that I get when run the script:

> In reproduceResults at 17
>
> Processing .\data\baby.mp4
>
> **Warning: Unable to determine the number of frames in this file.**
>
> Processing .\data\baby2.mp4
>
> Error using VideoReader/init (line 436)

I tried to open a file using VideoReader directly and this is the warning that I get:

```
>> videoObj = VideoReader('baby.mp4'); 
Warning: Unable to determine the number of frames in this file.
```

I followed the advice [from the MathWorks forum](http://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/49144-problems-obtaining-the-correct-number-of-frames-in-video-file) tried the get() function. This is the output:

```
>> get(videoObj)
  General Settings:
    Duration = 10.0333
    Name = baby.mp4
    Path = C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\EVM_Matlab-1.1\EVM_Matlab\data
    Tag = 
    Type = VideoReader
    UserData = []

  Video Settings:
    BitsPerPixel = 24
    FrameRate = 30.0000
    Height = 544
    NumberOfFrames = []
    VideoFormat = RGB24
    Width = 960
```

I am running MATLAB R2013a on Windows XP.

Comment: According to the Matlab documentation for  R2015a, the VideoReader  class can't determine the frame rate for video with a variable frame rate unless the last frame is read. They give a procedure to read the last frame [at this link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader-class.html). I can't find the doc for r2013a but it  may be worth trying this procedure if not much has changed.

Answer (score 6):

The VideoReader has to scan the entire file to determine the number of frames that are present in the file for certain file formats. The reason it has to do this is because of a class of files that have variable frame rate.

Typically, the frame-counting occurs during construction. However, for some files, it returns an empty.

To force, VideoReader to count the number of frames, read the last frame using

```
data = read(vidObj, Inf);
numFrames = vidObj.NumberOfFrames;
```

Hope this helps.

Dinesh

Comment: Thanks. This gives me the number of frames but I still don't know how to fix the original problem. How can I get the [Eulerian Video Magnification code](http://people.csail.mit.edu/mrub/evm/#code) to run properly?

Comment: The error in VideoReader/init indicates that VideoReader is unable to read the file baby2.mp4. Are u on Windows? If so, are you able to play the video using Windows Media Player? If not, you might need to install additional codecs to get the file to read.

Comment: I'm able to play baby.mp4 using Windows Media Player.

Comment: I think you are getting an error when VideoReader is trying to read baby2.mp4. Can you check if that video works?

Comment: baby2.mp4 is not created at all

Comment: You might want to contact the authors of this code to figure out what is going on as I am unaware of this code does.